# scrollview with offset, imitate bottom sheet

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I need to achieve something like this in this picture, so the layout with the content will scroll up above the background image. 
I have tried using ConstraintLayout and ScrollView with relations (0.4 to 0.6), but unable to achieve that behaviour, or simply the content in white is not scrollable.

[image]

Comment: try to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: tried, but the poster card view image doesn't overlapping with the AppBarLayout is buggy